# date range not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, datepicker

I'm having two issues with the same aspect of my application, the abstract view is this:

The app allows users to view different video clips. On the back-end/admin section the admin can track the views of any particular group of clips. For example, the admin can choose `Universal Studios`, select a `date range: Beginning Date: 2015-01-1, End Date: 2016-01-1` and hit `filter`, and see the number of total views that `Universal` received within this range.

The problem is, for one, **datepicker** is no longer working, so when I click on the date fields, no calendar appears, I manually have to type in the date. And for two, I'm only getting results between furthers: `2015-10-18` and `2016-02-18`. When I type in `2015-09-18` or anything earlier it doesn't generate results.

**See the code below, and let me know if you need any other code!**

**Index.html.erb snippit:**

```
<tr>
    <td><%= f.text_field :start_date, value: 1.month.ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :end_date, value: Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %></td>
    <td>
      <%= f.submit "Filter", class: "btn btn-danger", data: {disable_with: 'Searching...'} %>
      <%= link_to 'Clear Form', '#', id: "clear", class: 'btn btn-default'  %>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

**_impressions.html.erb snippit:**

```
    </style>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<% if @impressions.blank? -%>
<div class="span12"><h1>Nothing found</h1></div>
<% else %>
<div class="alert alert-success">
  <div class="">Total Views: <b><%= @impressions.count %></b></div>
  <div class="">Percentage to overall views: <b><%= @percentage.round(2) %>%</b></div>
</div>

<table id="table_3" class="table table_output">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="stat_head">Studio</td>
      <td class="stat_head">Film</td>
      <td class="stat_head">Clip</td>
      <td class="stat_head">User</td>
      <td class="stat_head">State</td>
      <td class="stat_head">Country</td>
      <td class="stat_head">Type</td>
      <td class="stat_head">Date</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @impressions.each do |impression| -%>
    <% @clip = Clip.where(id: impression.impressionable_id).first %>
    <% user = User.where(id: impression.user_id).first %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to @clip.film.studio.name,  saas_admin_studio_path(@clip.film.studio) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to @clip.film.name, saas_admin_studio_film_path(@clip.film.studio, @clip.film) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to @clip.name, saas_admin_studio_film_clips_path(@clip.film.studio ,@clip.film) %></td>
      <td><%= user.present? ? (link_to user.username, saas_admin_account_user_path(user.account, user)) : ' - ' %></td>
      <td><%= user.present? ? user.account.organization.state : ' - ' %></td>
      <td><%= user.present? ? user.account.organization.country_id : ' - ' %></td>
      <td><%= user.present? ? user.account.subscription.state : ' - ' %></td>
      <td><%= user.present? ? impression.created_at.strftime("%b %e, %Y %l:%M%P") : ' - ' %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like this :

```
<%=label_tag :start_date, "Start Date" %>
<input id="datepicker" name="someName" ...any other options>
```

then :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#datepicker").datepicker(); 
});
</script>
```

then of course add a similar field for `end_date` as well.

Note that you must include `//= require jquery-ui/datepicker` in your `application.js`

Comment: Right, thank you. Is there a solution to repair my existing code though? Because at one point, it did work.